# Calling a KeyDown Event on Form Load

Tags: c#, events

I would want to launch a `KeyDown` Event on `Form_Load` however its taking me somewhere else in the `Form_Load` event.

Form_Load:

```
int static_int = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(condition == true)
    {
        txtInput.Text = "something";
        txtInput.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
        int somegeneratednubmer = 20;
        static_int = static_int + somegeneratednumber;
        //somemore code here
    }

}
```

KeyDown:

```
private void txtInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
      static_int = 10;
      //somemore codes here too
  }
```

I would like to get the SUM of `static_int` and `somegeneratednumber` which is 30. However, after Debugging, I'm getting its initialized value of 0. From what I understood, after `SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")` the `KeyDown` event should proceed.

Why is it not??
How would I get the correct result? I really should do the `KeyDown` event on `Form_Load`, a conditional event...
or What am I doing wrong here?
**Note: originally static_int is initialized on a Class**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `KeyDown` even will proceed at the earliest possible moment, which is when the appropriate message is executed from the form's message queue. That cannot happen before the `Load` event finishes, because that *also* on the message queue. Even if that weren't the case, `SendKeys` doesn't *wait* for the action to be processed. It just sends the message and returns immediately.

Another problem is that `SendKeys` sends the virtual keys to the currently active window. That can never be your window, since your window isn't even shown yet! When something behaves weird, a good first step is to read the documentation.

So, why is the value of `static_int` zero, instead of `20` or `30`? Well, the likeliest case is an unhandled exception, and I'm pretty sure that's exactly what happens when you do `tbxInput.Focus`. The control doesn't quite exist yet, and it can't be made the input focus. If you have trouble understanding all this, you might want to find some book on the basics of how Windows windows work - there's nothing .NET can do about it, and it's places like this where the (very pretty) .NET abstraction leaks a lot. If you're planning to do any Windows UI development, you really need to know at least the basics.

However, that's completely unnecessary anyway. You don't have to execute a `KeyDown` event. Just make a method that's called from both the `Load` event handler and the `KeyDown` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this event instead
Form1 isn't loaded yet so no events yet.

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
}
```

But truly this design is wrong